# Where is .AddDbContext method?

Tags: asp.net-core

Everywhere it's said to call services.AddDbContext<> method but it is not recognized inside the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to reference the correct package first, which depends on the EF Core provider you want to use.

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` for SQL Server, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` for SQLite and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` for in memory (only for testing).

These are the official out-of-the-box providers. There are also 3rd party providers for PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc. The documentation providers a list of available 3rd party providers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/).

Also depending on the provider you may also need to declare a certain namespace. The built-in providers are declared in `Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection` namespace so you need to add a `using Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection;` to the top of your `Startup.cs`.

Other providers (Oracle's MySQL provider for example) uses `MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions` namespace, so you need to define this using `using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;`

Comment: So, utilizing a part of EF is essential, even if not using EF? I'm wishing to use Dapper, so should I still be using this dependency?

Comment: If you are using `DbContext` (and hence require AddDbContext), then **you are** using EF. Dapper is completely unrelated to EF and is based on `IDbConnection` and doesn't use `DbContext`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out shortly after writing it. Didn't intend to rubber duck with you - thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Note when actually writing the `using` you only have to reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` omitting the specific package name. Providing it seems to throw an error.